# What numbers can be approximated "pretty well" by rationals?

Tags: diophantine-approximation

More precisely, what real numbers $r$ have the following property: for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exist infinitely many pairs $(p, q)$ of integers such that

$$\left| \frac{p}{q} - r \right| < \frac{\epsilon}{q^2}.$$

I think that this is impossible if $r$ is a quadratic irrational.  On the other hand, it's certainly possible for any number with [irrationality measure](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) strictly greater than $2$.

What I really want to know is if the real numbers which don't have the property above have measure zero.  If that's true, it would answer [the last part of this math.SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7634/you-are-standing-at-the-origin-of-an-infinite-forest-holding-an-infinite-bb-gu/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a well-studied question in diophantine approximation. You can look up Markov or Lagrange spectrum for a "description" of the numbers for which you cannot take $\epsilon$ arbitrarily small. For the answer to your last question, look up Khinchin's theorem (the answer is no, they have full measure).

Comment: Thanks, Felipe!  I can't seem to find a statement of Khinchin's theorem (I assume you're not referring to the theorem about Khinchin's constant) online.  Do you have a reference?

Comment: http://eom.springer.de/d/d032580.htm

Comment: If I read it correctly, the answer is yes, almost all real numbers can be approximated pretty well by rationals. 

Comment: For intuition, large coefficients in the simple continued fraction expansion produce good rational approximations. There is a limiting distribution for the coefficients, the Gauss-Kuzmin distribution, which is supported on all positive integers, so you expect that with some coarse independence that you get infinitely many coefficients greater than any fixed size except on a set of measure $0$. 

Comment: @Douglas: Now I am confused, too many double negations. Most numbers can be well approximated.

Answer (score 1):

[Hardy and Wright](http://books.google.com.eg/books?id=rey9wfSaJ9EC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Hardyand+wright+number&source=bl&ots=avj7HPEGSa&sig=ZBqVYG6xeXOSbwcC5mUxM-ql_uQ&hl=ar&ei=pdHFTLeQOca54gb28OC6Aw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) devoted a chapter (chapter 9) to these questions. One interesting theorem related to your question is theorem 196.